# \eqnum, really basic use

Tags: equations, numbering

I repeat a (regression) equation in order to contrast the original equation with alternatives.  The target journal's template says in that case to use `\eqnum` and manually insert the repeated number.  But when I run this minimal example, the equation is numbered 1 rather than 4, as if there were no `\eqnum` command.  If instead I put `\eqnum{4}` after ...\delta, which is where I think it belongs, the file won't typeset.  I'm using TexShop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\eqnum{4}
\sigma+\delta
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This question is so simple that I'm quite surprised not to have found the solution.  But I've spent well over an hour looking (probably in the wrong places) and haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't typeset as-is, regardless of where you place `\eqnum`, since `\eqnum` does not exist. The publisher may be referring to `\tag`. As in, `\tag{4}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

See this equation:
\begin{equation}
  \sigma + \delta
  \tag{4}\label{eqn:important}
\end{equation}

There's also this variation:
\begin{equation}
  \sigma' + \delta'
  \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Or you can use:
\begin{equation}
  \sigma'' + \delta''
  \tag{\ref{eqn:important}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can `\newcommand{\eqnum}{\tag}` in your preamble, which will allow you to use `\eqnum` just like `\tag`.